# Excel Lookup from different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

i have sheet in below formats

Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2

[image]

Now i have to validate my Sheet1 as per Sheet 2 if ID exist and country present its "Match" else "No Match" if no entry then "No Data"

```
 =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(VLOOKUP(A6,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$2,2,0),B2))
```

Comment: so you want to check if the city part of the master location from sheet 1, exists on sheet 2 ?

Comment: also is singapore l xxx.... in cell A6 on sheet 1 ?

Comment: i want to check master location from sheet 1 , exists in Sheet 2

Comment: let me reformat my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding to Sheet1 another column to isolate the country name.
The formula would be:
`=LEFT(C2, SEARCH("|",C2)-1)`.

Now you may use VLOOKUP to validate the values.

I note that using the functions of INDEX and MATCH is often faster and more
flexible than using VLOOKUP.
For details see for example the article
[How to Use Index Match Instead of Vlookup](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/index-match-formula/).

Comment: Thanks but how to check and compare ID then for country name ?

Comment: Read the article in my link. You may also need the EXACT function to compare the retrieved string with the one in the column. The result of the comparison can be in some new "Valid" column that will signal if the value is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you it worked !